# Exogenity: What does E(eX) really mean and why is it used?

Tags: least-squares, conditional-expectation, asymptotics, exogeneity, gauss-markov-theorem

What does it mean to talk about the expectation of the product of the error term and an independent variable? Like, why do we even need to mention $E(e_i X_{ik})$? What is it actually describing or what is the intuition behind it?

So for a linear regression model

$Y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 X_{i2} + e_i$

When people talked about strict exogenity $E(e_i | x_{i2}) = 0$, I found that they often mention something like $E(e_i X_{i2}) = 0$ or $E(e_i Y_i) = 0$, and I just don't understand why. I mean, how did they jump from conditional expectation to the exception of a product, and why?

This question confused me for months. Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me write the model as $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\dots+\beta_px_p+e$, or $y=\mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}+e$, $\mathbf{x}=(1,x_1,\dots,x_p)$, $\boldsymbol{\beta}=(\beta_0,\dots,\beta_p)$.

$E[e\mathbf{x}]$ follows from $E[e\mid \mathbf{x}]=0$. In general, if $E[e\mid \mathbf{x}]=0$, then

- $E[e]=0$ by the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
  $$E[e]=E[E[e\mid \mathbf{x}]]=E[0]=0$$
- $E[f(\mathbf{x})e]=0$, where $f(\mathbf{x})$ is an arbitrary finite valued function, by the same law: $E[f(\mathbf{x})e]=E[E[f(\mathbf{x})e\mid\mathbf{x}]]$, but when $\mathbf{x}$ is given, $f(\mathbf{x})$ is given too, so:
  $$E[f(\mathbf{x})e]=E[E[f(\mathbf{x})e\mid\mathbf{x}]]=E[f(\mathbf{x})E[e\mid\mathbf{x}]]=0$$
- $E[\mathbf{x}e]=0$: let $f$ be the identity function.
- $E[y\mid\mathbf{x}]=\mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

If $E[e]=0$ and $E[\mathbf{x}e]=0$, then $\mathbf{x}$ and $e$ are uncorrelated:
$$\text{Cov}(\mathbf{x},e)=E[\mathbf{x}e]-E[\mathbf{x}]E[e]=0$$

> What does it mean to talk about the expectation of the product of the
> error term and an independent variable? Like, why do we even need to
> mention E(eiXik)? What is it actually describing or what is the
> intuition behind it?

In other words: what happens if $\mathbf{x}$ and $e$ are *not* uncorrelated?

Let's say that the 'true' model is:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+e$$
but your model is:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+u$$
where $u=\beta_2x_2+e$.

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated, say $x_2=cx_1$, then:

- $E[u]=E[\beta_2x_2+e]=E[\beta_2cx_1+e]=\beta_2cE[x_1]\ne 0$
- $E[y\mid x_1]\ne \beta_0+\beta_1x_1$
- $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ will be biased and inconsistent.