# Random Sampling: Weak and Strong Exogenity

Tags: sampling, conditional-expectation, asymptotics, exogeneity, gauss-markov-theorem

$Y \ = \ X' \beta \ + \ e $

Where $Y = (y_1, ..., y_n)$ and $\beta = (\beta_0,..., \beta_k)$.

Why would Weak Exogenity under random sampling produce Strong Exogenity?

I know that weak exogenity is defined as $ \ E(e_i | x_i) = 0 \hspace{1em} \forall \ i \ $ and
strong exogenity is defined as $E(e_i | x_j) = 0 \hspace{1em} \forall \ i,j \in \left\lbrace 1, \cdots, n \right\rbrace $.

And I didn't understand the claim that
$ \ \ E(e_i | X) = E(e_i | x_1, \cdots, x_n) = E(e_i | x_i) = 0 \ \ $

I know $ \ \ E(e_i| x_i, x_j) = E(e_i| x_i) \ \ $ if $e_i$ is independent of $x_j$.

And I thought that random sampling is about $e_i$ being independent of $e_j$ for $i \neq j$. (or is it about $x_i$ and $x_j$? I'm confused...)

But why would $e_i$ be independent of $x_j$s due to random sampling?

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random sampling is about the multivariate realization $(y_i,x_{1i},x_{2i},...x_{ki})$
and imply that realization $i$ is independent of any others. $i=1,...,n$

Moreover the condition $E[e_i|x_{1i},x_{2i},...x_{ki}]=0$ imply $E[e_i|x_{ji}]=0$ fon any $j=1,...,k$. In word, and in the sense that you intend, strict exogeneity imply the weak.

So the claim that you do not understand is correct.

I see that you looking for other related statistical aspects here: [Exogenity: What does E(eX) really mean and why is it used?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486049/exogenity-what-does-eex-really-mean-and-why-is-it-used)

All of them are relevant. Maybe you are student and I do not want to put you in the confusion. However I have to warning you that the proper meaning of exogeneity not stay in detail about usual statistical dependence measures (mean independance, scorrelation, orthogonality, indipendence, conditional independence, ecc): **Exogeneity have, or should have, a clear causal role**. This role must be enclosed in *causal models*, then the role of *structural equations*, not only regression equations, is crucial. Read here can help:

[What is the actual definition of endogeneity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262609/what-is-the-actual-definition-of-endogeneity/402015#402015)

[How are standard exogeneity assumptions and indepent of potential outcomes concepts linked?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483316/how-are-standard-exogeneity-assumptions-and-indepent-of-potential-outcomes-conce)

[Zero conditional expectation of error in OLS regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483598/zero-conditional-expectation-of-error-in-ols-regression/483612#483612)

[Endogeneity testing using correlation test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477978/endogeneity-testing-using-correlation-test/478091#478091)